# Forcasting from a time series that has structural breaks

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

From the instructions given in http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.com/2012/04/ and by following up the examples listed I understand detecting structural breaks. Can someone please help me with after identifying the structural breaks how to go for forecasting using R. Below is the codes from the web page sited above.

```
library(bfast)
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC",from="1950-01-01")
GSPC.monthly <- log(to.monthly(GSPC)[,4])
GSPC.ts <- ts(as.vector(GSPC.monthly["1951-01::"]),start=c(1951,1),frequency=12)
GSPC.stl <- stl(GSPC.ts,s.window="periodic")
plot(GSPC.stl,main="STL Decomposition of S&P 500")

GSPC.bfast <- bfast(GSPC.ts,h=0.2,max.iter=1,season="none")
plot(GSPC.bfast,type="components",ylim=c(3,max(GSPC.monthly)+1),main="S&P 500 with bfast Breakpoints and Components")
plot(GSPC.bfast,type="trend",ylim=c(3,max(GSPC.monthly)+1),main="S&P 500 with bfast Trend Breakpoints")
GSPC.bfast$output[[1]]$St
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite challenging to forecast after a structural break. First of all: If you use some type of rolling regression the structural break no longer effects your model after some time. (Depending on the length of the window). For more advanced method have a look at [Eklund et al. 2010](https://ideas.repec.org/p/boe/boeewp/0406.html). After a structural break they mix the pre-break and a new post-break model. Of course the parameter calibration is tricky.